# Xcode comment selection shortcut not working on European keyboard

Tags: xcode

I have an Apple keyboard (Norwegian) with numeric keypad and I can't get the Xcode shortcut for comment selection (cmd + /) to work. I have to change to Input source = US every time I want to comment out a block.  When I change from US to Norwegian input source the Xcode -> Editor -> Structure -> comment selection shortcut disappears.

Does anyone know why changing input source from Norwegian/Swedish/German (I guess all European languages) have this effect.  What is the "European" shortcut for comment selection ?

Are Europeans not allowed by Apple to comment select..!? ;-)

Any ideas would be much appreciated !

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you should ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com as this isn't a programming question.

Comment: h@trojanfoe ok sure, should I delete it ?

Comment: Yeah I reckon so; I am assuming this issue isn't restricted to Xcode only?

Comment: @trojanfoe No, this is just Xcode, in Sublime text it works fine

Comment: Hmmm. I think that makes it on-topic; I will delete my close vote.

Comment: It works on French Keyboard, using Cmd+/+Maj (since / is obtained with "Maj + :"

Comment: Yeah I tried that, CMD+SHIFT+7, I also have a Numeric Keypad, with a dedicated button for / (above 9). So it should work just CMD + /.   So what does it say on Xcode menu, does it give you the shortcut there, or is it blank ?

Comment: @larme I see that if I change to French input source, the comment selection shortcut appears back in Xcode -> Editor -> Structure -> comment selection... The French are lucky, Apple trust you with comment selection :-)

Comment: This question was answered here:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214236/xcode-comment-selection-shortcut-not-working-on-european-keyboard/214243?noredirect=1#comment258631_214243